# Multiple Tabs In One Page Using Jquery Css

Tags: jquery, css, tabs

i have two problem with this jquery method :

1- in css hover and active not change link color ! `Gallery` or `Submit`

2- after click in tab3 or tab4 ( id 3- id 4 ) hidden tabcontent for id 1.

```
<div><ul class="tabs">
    <li><a href="#tab1">Gallery</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab2">Submit</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab_container">
        <div id="tab1" class="tab_content">
            <!--Content-->
        </div>
        <div id="tab2" class="tab_content">
            <!--Content-->
        </div>
    </div></div>
<div>
    <ul class="tabs">
        <li><a href="#tab3">Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab4">Submit</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab_container">
        <div id="tab3" class="tab_content">
            <!--Content-->
        </div>
        <div id="tab4" class="tab_content">
            <!--Content-->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function() {

    //When page loads...
    $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all content
    $("ul.tabs li:first").addClass("active").show(); //Activate first tab
    $(".tab_content:first").show(); //Show first tab content
    //On Click Event
    $("ul.tabs li").click(function() {

        $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class
        $(this).addClass("active"); //Add "active" class to selected tab
        $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all tab content
        var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); //Find the href attribute value to identify the active tab + content
        $(activeTab).fadeIn(); //Fade in the active ID content
        return false;
    });

});

ul.tabs {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    height: 32px; /*--Set height of tabs--*/
    border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
    border-left: 1px solid #999;
    width: 100%;
}
ul.tabs li {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 31px; /*--Subtract 1px from the height of the unordered list--*/
    line-height: 31px; /*--Vertically aligns the text within the tab--*/
    border: 1px solid #999;
    border-left: none;
    margin-bottom: -1px; /*--Pull the list item down 1px--*/
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    background: #e0e0e0;
}
ul.tabs li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    padding: 0 20px;
    border: 1px solid #fff; /*--Gives the bevel look with a 1px white border inside the list item--*/
    outline: none;
}
ul.tabs li a:hover {
    background: #ccc;
}
html ul.tabs li.active, html ul.tabs li.active a:hover  { /*--Makes sure that the active tab does not listen to the hover properties--*/
    background: #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff; /*--Makes the active tab look like it's connected with its content--*/
}
.tab_container {
    border: 1px solid #999;
    border-top: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    clear: both;
    float: left; width: 100%;
    background: #fff;
}
.tab_content {
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

How To Fix This! [LIVE Action Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eSHdb/1/)

Comment: Why are you using such old versions of jQuery and jQueryui?

Comment: You can build a custom download. http://jqueryui.com/download

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are hiding elements by class. `$(".tab_content").hide()` hides all your content elements regardless of tab setup.

You should wrap your tabs and it´s content areas and select the element relative to that wrapper element.

**UPDATE**

Created short [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RwPps/) for you.

```
$(".myTabs").each(function() {

    var $myTabs = $(this);

    $myTabs.find(".tab_content").hide().first().show();
    $myTabs.find("ul.tabs li:first").addClass("active").show();

    $myTabs.find("ul.tabs li").click(function() {
        var $this = $(this);

        $this.addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
        $myTabs.find(".tab_content").hide();

        var activeTab = $this.find("a").attr("href");
        $(activeTab).fadeIn();

        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: This Not Worked !! after click in submit Not Remove Gallery Content !! put content into gallery / submit ! see this error

Answer (score 0):

Correct Answer is this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$(".myTabs").each(function() {

    var $myTabs = $(this);

    $myTabs.find(".tab_content").hide().first().show();
    $myTabs.find("ul.tabs li:first").addClass("active").show();

    $myTabs.find("ul.tabs li").click(function() {
        var $this = $(this);

        $this.addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
        $myTabs.find(".tab_content").hide();

        var activeTab = $this.find("a").attr("href");
        $(activeTab).fadeIn();

        return false;
    });
});
```

});